# How to set CGBITMAP_CONTEXT_LOG_ERRORS environmental variable?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-graphics

While using `CGBitmapContextCreate` I get error in XCode

> CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: set
>   CGBITMAP_CONTEXT_LOG_ERRORS environmental variable to see the details

How can I set this var?

I tried
`launchctl setenv CGBITMAP_CONTEXT_LOG_ERRORS /Users/user/Documents/cgbitmap_errors.log` and `launchctl setenv CGBITMAP_CONTEXT_LOG_ERRORS 1` and restarting XCode with no success.

I also tried combination with `defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode UseSanitizedBuildSystemEnvironment -bool NO`, no success too

I restarted computer too

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Environmental variables can be set in the product scheme editor (in Xcode) like shown in the screenshot:

Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme... (⌘<)
[image: Scheme editor screenshot]

Comment: The value should be 1, as stated in the question.